# Why is onActivityReenter not called?

Tags: android, transition, android-lifecycle, shared-element-transition

I override method

> ```
> override fun onActivityReenter(resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
>     super.onActivityReenter(resultCode, data)
> }
> ```

for shared-element-transition. However, when i place debug on this method, I see it has never been called when comeback from another activity. How to use it ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to add debug inside the method not to the method it self.

Comment: I debug inside the method but it not jump to +_+

Comment: I curiously want to know why don't you use `onActivityResult` callback instead.

Comment: For using Shared-Element transition between viewpager and recyclerview. You can see code in below links.I clone code from this github debug on that method, it can jump into. However, when I create new application, debug break point never jump into.
https://github.com/andremion/Louvre/blob/development/louvre/src/main/java/com/andremion/louvre/home/GalleryActivity.java
https://github.com/andremion/Louvre/blob/development/louvre/src/main/java/com/andremion/louvre/home/GalleryFragment.java
https://github.com/andremion/Louvre
(Ở VN ít làm animation sao í, cái này ra hồi android5 mà ko ai biết)

Comment: @HienNguyen thank you! I have new keyword to research!

Comment: @TaQuangTu Please like my question post if it is helpful to you :(

Comment: @HienNguyen :)). The question is not useful for me, but your comment, i will just upvote your comment as useful (em cũng đang tập tành học android có gì mong anh chỉ giáo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195328/discussion-between-ta-quang-tu-and-hien-nguyen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Conditions for this method working
First: Using ActivityOptions when startActivity

> startActivityForResult(
>                   Intent(this, TestActivity2::class.java),
>                   1000,
>                   ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, fab, "hien").toBundle())

Second: Have to call setResult method before go back